# ImageMagick -liquid-rescale option error

Tags: linux, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, seam-carving

I want to use Seam Carving,  and found [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale) maybe a good choice.
Then I install ImageMagick from source as [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale) indicate.

My problem is: When I type the command
`convert logo_trimmed.jpg  -liquid-rescale 75x100%\!  logo_lqr.jpg`
it gives the following error:
`convert: delegate library support not built-in 'logo_trimmed.jpg' (LQR) @ error/resize.c/LiquidRescaleImage/1900.`

I thought it may because lack of `liblqr` support, so I go to [Liquid Rescale](http://liblqr.wikidot.com/) to install it
and then `make uninstall` ImageMagick and install it again.
However, problem remains the same.

Can anyone tell me how to make `convert -liquid-rescale`  works?
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

After installing `liblqr`, you have to install imagemagick by running `configure` prior to `make`, see build instructions here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix

If you don't run `configure` it will not pick your new library.

And after you've compiled imagemagick check that `LQR` delegate library was installed by running:

```
convert -list configure | grep -i "delegates"
```

and seeing LQR listed there.

Comment: Thanks for help. After did as you told, it gives:   `DELEGATES      mpeg fontconfig freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lzma openexr pango png ps tiff x xml zlib` (DELEGATES is in red)  But the original error remains the same.